# Emulator for Samsung Galaxy s4 not working in eclipse

Tags: android

I need to test my android App on Galaxy s4(1080 X 1920 441dpi) , So I have created an  AVD for GalaxyS4 but the problem is that when i lunch the emulator and unlock the screen Lock the emulator screen becomes black then the device  disconnected "the emulator stopped working ", Please help me how can i solve this problem ? its very very important to test my app on Galaxy s4 and  I don't have s4 real device .. please help me ...

[image: Creating device for Galaxy S4]

[image: AVD for S4]

Comment: Please any help would be greatly appreciated ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue seems to be with your Memory options. For you, I've created the AVD for S4 with additional RAM and Heap sizes. Please follow my screenshots and re-create the same. I tried this with both versions API-18 and API-19 and it's bingo :)
[image]
I suggest you, to delete the existing AVD S4 at your end and start creating it afresh like guided in the screenshot

My observation is with API-19 works well so, suggest you to work with API-19 for this S4. In case if you don't have API-19, use SDK Manager to get installed.

Best of luck

Comment: @Gem_RamThanks thank you very very much for helping me , Its working now , I would like to ensure from some thing about s4 its xhdpi snce its 441dpi true?? or its xxhdpi??

Comment: The emulator its too slow is there any way to increase its speed?? can you help me more please ?

Comment: Galaxy S4 -- 1080 x 1920 pixels -- 5.0" -- 441 ppi -- xxhdpi and Nexus 4 -- 1280 x  768 pixels -- 4.7" -- 320 ppi -- xhdpi and about speed, I believe you've decent computer with sufficient RAM size like 4GB or more with good System Processor. Other option is Go to --> TaskManager --> Processes --> select 'emlator-arm.exe' --> Right Click --> Select 'Set Affinity' --> Select all CPUs available. For e.g. in my case CPU0 and CPU1. See it should help a bit

Comment: @Gem_RamThanks alot,but from where i can find Task manager ?? i didn't find it in eclipse

Comment: Welcome and No problems. Not in Eclipse...I'm talking about Windows Task Manager

Comment: Ok I will try it , Unfortunately I have encountered a problem: While testing my app on the emulator a black background cover part of the emulator screen and  when i click on a button or even the screen  its cover  what i click  also ! do you have seen this problem before? How can i solve this problem  ?